# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parseAlgParameters failed: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, ssl-certificate

In my one AWS EC2 server, I deployed three services [Auth, orders, Security]. I configured SSL for three services, The SSL is the same for three services, The Auth orders services working fine after doing some tunning, but the Security service has 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parseAlgParameters failed: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)' problem.
My Server has below **Java Version**:
openjdk version "**1.8.0_302**"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_302-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.302-b08, mixed mode)
I deployed my jar files from my windows PC, for my windows PC all three services working fine. but it's an issue with my AWS Centos server.

initially, I converted my .crt file to .p12 with Openssl3, that time all my three services has the above issue. So degraded my OpenSSL to the 1.1.1 version. then build my jars to AWS. So 'Auth' and 'Order' services are started working. but still am having issue in my security service.
below is the pom.xml for authentication.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.lc.auth</groupId>
    <artifactId>AuthenticationService</artifactId>
    <version>MVP-V2.0.0</version>
    <name>AuthenticationService</name>
    <description>Authentication Service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

            
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>





        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>   

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-oauth2-jose -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
     <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>7.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.imgscalr</groupId>
    <artifactId>imgscalr-lib</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

below is the Auth application.properties file

```
server.port=8282
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store: classpath:localhost.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: XXXXXX08
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12




spring.datasource.url=jdbc:ipaddr:3306/db_authentications?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=xxxx


spring.data.jdbc.repositories.enabled=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true

spring.datasource.max-active=100 # advanced configuration...
spring.datasource.max-idle=100
spring.datasource.min-idle=8
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false

spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false


logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate: ERROR


spring.main.banner-mode=off


#server.undertow.accesslog.enabled=true
#server.undertow.accesslog.dir=target/logs
#server.undertow.accesslog.pattern=combined
#server.compression.enabled=true
#server.compression.min-response-size=1



# Enable response compression
server.compression.enabled=true

# The comma-separated list of mime types that should be compressed
server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json

# Compress the response only if the response size is at least 1KB
server.compression.min-response-size=1000

# Enable HTTP/2 support, if the current environment supports it
server.http2.enabled=true

# Maximum time the response should be cached (in seconds) 
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.max-age=120

# The cache must re-validate stale resources with the server. Any expired resources must not be used without re-validating.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.must-revalidate=true

# The resources are private and intended for a single user. They must not be stored by a shared cache (e.g CDN).
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.cache-private= false 

# The resources are public and any cache may store the response.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.cache-public= true 

spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true

# Write files to disk if the file size is more than 2KB.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB

# The intermediate disk location where the uploaded files are written
spring.servlet.multipart.location=/tmp

# Maximum file size that can be uploaded
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB

# Maximum allowed multipart request size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=75MB

spring.task.execution.pool.keep-alive = 60s
server.undertow.always-set-keep-alive = false
```

below is Security Service pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.lc.inventory.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>LittleCarrotsInventorySecurityService</artifactId>
    <version>MVP-V2.0.0</version>
    <name>LittleCarrotsInventorySecurityService</name>
    <description>Little Carrots Inventory Security Service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <!-- 
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
-->

        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.undertow/undertow-core -->
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
-->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.undertow/undertow-servlet -->
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
            <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>






        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.lettuce</groupId>
            <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-oauth2-jose -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
    <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
    <version>7.9</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.3</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

below is Security service application.properties file

```
server.port= 8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store: classpath:localhost.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password: xxxxx
server.ssl.keyStoreType: PKCS12

spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration

spring.h2.console.enabled=true


#LIVE DB URLS ENABLE ON MAIN STREAM
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://ipadr:3306/main_securityservice?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=xxxx   



spring.data.jdbc.repositories.enabled=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true

spring.datasource.max-active=100 # advanced configuration...
spring.datasource.max-idle=100
spring.datasource.min-idle=8
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false

spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false


logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate: ERROR


spring.main.banner-mode=off



#server.undertow.accesslog.enabled=true
#server.undertow.accesslog.dir=target/logs
#server.undertow.accesslog.pattern=combined
#server.compression.enabled=true
#server.compression.min-response-size=1



# Enable response compression
server.compression.enabled=true

# The comma-separated list of mime types that should be compressed
server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json

# Compress the response only if the response size is at least 1KB
server.compression.min-response-size=1000

# Enable HTTP/2 support, if the current environment supports it
server.http2.enabled=true

# Maximum time the response should be cached (in seconds) 
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.max-age=120

# The cache must re-validate stale resources with the server. Any expired resources must not be used without re-validating.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.must-revalidate=false

# The resources are private and intended for a single user. They must not be stored by a shared cache (e.g CDN).
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.cache-private= false 

# The resources are public and any cache may store the response.
spring.resources.cache.cachecontrol.cache-public= false 

spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true

# Write files to disk if the file size is more than 2KB.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB

# The intermediate disk location where the uploaded files are written
spring.servlet.multipart.location=/tmp

# Maximum file size that can be uploaded
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=50MB

# Maximum allowed multipart request size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=75MB


spring.task.execution.pool.keep-alive = 60s
server.undertow.always-set-keep-alive = false

server.undertow.eager-filter-init=true
```

after the some references I updated open jdk also but no solution, below is full exception details.

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at com.lc.sk.inventory.security.SecurityServiceApplication.main(SecurityServiceApplication.java:15) [classes!/:MVP-V2.0.0]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) [SecurityService-MVP-V2.0.0.jar:MVP-V2.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:109) [SecurityService-MVP-V2.0.0.jar:MVP-V2.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) [SecurityService-MVP-V2.0.0.jar:MVP-V2.0.0]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) [SecurityService-MVP-V2.0.0.jar:MVP-V2.0.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.3.0.RELEASE]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1058) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parseAlgParameters failed: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:99) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:71) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:216) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1141) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:592) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1055) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: parseAlgParameters failed: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)
        at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.parseAlgParameters(PKCS12KeyStore.java:829) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
        at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:2037) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
        at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.security.KeyStoreUtil.load(KeyStoreUtil.java:67) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:216) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:207) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getKeyManagers(SSLUtilBase.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.createSSLContext(SSLUtilBase.java:246) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar!/:9.0.35]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)
        at sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier.<init>(ObjectIdentifier.java:285) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
        at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getOID(DerInputStream.java:320) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
        at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES2Parameters.engineInit(PBES2Parameters.java:267) ~[sunjce_provider.jar:1.8.0_302]
        at java.security.AlgorithmParameters.init(AlgorithmParameters.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
        at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.parseAlgParameters(PKCS12KeyStore.java:825) ~[na:1.8.0_302]
        ... 42 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Is there a specific solution to this one? facing the same issue

Comment: can you check SSL files beside of .properties file or not

Comment: makesure .p12 and .properties should be in resources/ folder

Answer (score 5):

In my case, it also happens on jks file.
The jks file is produced by Java-11 keytool, and consumed by Java-8.

We need to recreate the jks using Java-8 keytool.

Comment: Yes, use same version j8/j11

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to fix `server.port=8282` in you both properties files.
make sure to have the same port either `8282` or `8443` in both files.

Comment: I think its not port issue, i configured three port number for each service , Auth: 8282, Orders: 8283, Security: 8443,

Comment: See [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8267837) what i found I think this will help you it says that the issue demonstrates an interoperability issue where older 7u/8u JDKs can't parse the new algorithms DER encoded stream due to bug JDK-8202837. Hope it will help you

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, yes it's true, I went through all related links. I resolved this issue, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After the debug I found the same issue in my windows system. I regenerated .p12 certificate and deployed it. Now it's working fine.
The actual issue, private.key file wrong file placed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was running my Spring application on Java 11 and it worked fine but when I build a Docker image using JDK 8 in my Dockerfile and try to deploy it fails and throws the error:

```
java.io.IOException: parseAlgParameters failed: 
ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = 48)
```

This was because my Dockerfile was from JDK 8

After I downgraded my default IDE's JDK version to 8 I started getting the same error on my console.

Fixed it by updating my JDK versions.